# htaccess rewriting to remove query parameters

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

i have been trying to find the solution through previous question on SO, but im getting errors when using them.
how to make this url : `/viewpost.php?postid=81` as `/viewpost/81` in the url so that when `/viewpost/81` is entered, it shows the content of `/viewpost.php?postid=81`?

Answer (score 0):

You must capture the number and append this number as part of the query string

```
RewriteRule ^viewpost/(\d+)$ /viewpost.php?postid=$1 [L]
```

Comment: @user2216267 It works in my test environment. What happens, when you enter `www.example.com/viewpost/81`? Maybe the script is in some subdirectory?

Comment: i have written this code in the .htaccess file: "RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^viewpost/(\d+)$ /viewpost.php?postid=$1 [L]" but it is showing the urls as it is(viewpost.php?postid=81).