# Wordpress custom post type and custom taxonomy url rewrite

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

Hello i have a wordpress website that has this current link structure
http://www.timorcarsales.com/buy-car-timor-leste/?make=honda
I would like to have something like this
http://www.timorcarsales.com/buy-car-timor-leste/honda

The cars are added through a custom pot type, and the make comes form a custom taxonomy

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you and have a nice day!

Comment: Maybe this question helps http://stackoverflow.com/q/16155620/1741542

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy & Check below code in your function.php file.

```
function add_custom_rewrite_tag(){
    add_rewrite_tag('%make%', '([^&]+)');
}

add_action('init', 'add_custom_rewrite_tag', 10, 0);

function add_custom_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^buy-car-timor-leste/([^/]*)/?','index.php?page_id='.templateID.'&make=$matches[1]','top'); 
}

add_action('init', 'add_custom_rewrite_rule', 10, 0);
```